# Editor Templates in angularjs with WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, mvc-editor-templates

**Environment:**

I am using WebAPI and angularjs for my project.

**Problem:**

I need to dynamically create html for my models. I am thinking same as like EditorTemplates in MVC. So i create one html and based on datatype, the input box need to create.

**My Solution:**

I can sent the meta data(for each field name, datatype and value) in json and based on this create html tags.

Any general solution or articles for this. I feel like it is heavy to sent all this metada in every model json

Comment: I got a solution with example in this link even if it sending metadata in json object- https://metabroadcast.com/blog/dynamic-web-views-generation-with-angularjs